# Wierd behaviour in My SQL query

Tags: mysql, comparison

[image: Database]

I have a database with columns shown above. Whenever, i try to execute the query

```
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE `Answer` LIKE '123' "
```

, mysql is able to return the respective row. However, when i execute the same query to find the other 2 rows,

```
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE `Answer` LIKE '456' "
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE `Answer` LIKE '789' "
```

My sql returns with 0 results. These rows have been inserted via a POST request from a previous html form.If However, I try to insert the same rows manually with phpmyAdmin, it is able to detect the new rows.
What exactly is going on? I have been trying to figure out for a long time and can't understand why.

Comment: There must be something in the field that we cannot see. A blank, a tab or the like. Try `select concat('>', answer, '<'), length(answer) from crosswordpuzzles where answer like '%456%'` to check this.

Comment: (And anyway, Rahul Tripathi is right to mention that you should not use `LIKE` when really only `=` is needed. Don't tell the DBMS to run through complicated pattern matching algorithms, when you merely want to compare two strings for equality.)

Comment: What is `answer` actually? You are showing a number in your sample data, but what is it supposed to be really? Are you going to put a text in there (i.e. 'just because' for the first question) or is `answer` to contain an ID to an answer table or what else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. This may help you.

```
SELECT * FROM crosswordpuzzles WHERE Answer LIKE '%789%'
```

The above SQL statement selects all records where `Answer` containing the pattern "789".

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use the `LIKE` keyword when you are looking for exact result. Instead try to use IN like

```
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE `Answer` IN ('789','123','456') "
```

and if you are searching individual search then simply search using `=` like

```
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE `Answer` = '789'"
```

Or it might be that there are some space so you can try like

```
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE TRIM(`Answer`) = '789'"
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE TRIM(`Answer`) = '123'"
"SELECT * FROM `crosswordpuzzles` WHERE TRIM(`Answer`) = '456'"
```

Comment: I tried using  =   but it still gives me the same problem

Comment: @LewWeiHao:- Is the `Answer` column a varchar?

Comment: @LewWeiHao:- Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I have tried using TRIM but it is still unable to detect the first 2 rows

Comment: @LewWeiHao:- Thats strange! Did you check that the rows exist in table

Comment: @LewWeiHao There may be some space after or before the values in 'Answer' field, So using % before and after the search string will always help you to find the value you are looking for.